# Why does this binding only work for the first three times I change the value?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Consider the following snippet:

```js
var ITEMS = ["Item 1", "Item 2"]

window.App = Ember.Application.create();
window.App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend({
    sItems: ITEMS,
    sValue: ITEMS[0],
    sLabel: Ember.computed('sValue', function() {
        return this.get('sValue') == ITEMS[0] ?
            "You picked item 1!" :
            "You picked item 2!";
    })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/tags/v1.13.5/ember.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://builds.emberjs.com/release/ember-template-compiler.js"></script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars">
    {{view "select" content=sItems value=sValue}}
    {{sLabel}}
</script>
```

After changing the value of the `<select>` three times, it no longer triggers changes to the `sValue` property. Consequently, the label no longer changes.

I have been able to reproduce this in Chrome and Safari on OS X, IE11 on Windows 8.1, and Firefox and Chromium on Linux. (You should be able to reproduce it as well by running the snippet above.)

What am I doing wrong?

---

**Edit:** this appears to be [a known bug](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11817) introduced in Ember.js v1.13.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you have encountered this bug ["Ember.Select stops updating value property after a couple of option changes, introduced in 1.13.4"](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/issues/11817)

Answer (score 1):

Using `{{view 'select'}}` view helper (and `views` at all) is deprecated in Ember 1.13.

Read [Deprecation Guide: Ember.Select](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_ember-select) for details and possible workarounds.

See also [Deprecation Guide: Ember.View](http://emberjs.com/deprecations/v1.x/#toc_ember-view)